# Clone User, copy all files and folders and copy rights (Linux)

Tags: linux, ssh, chmod, chown

I want to create a new user in Linux, basically creating an exact copy of that user with all permission and access, read and write rights on all folders, subfolders and files (including hidden files).

It does not seem like an easy task. I am able to copy all files but I am not able to clone the rights for all files and subfolders.

What is the right procedure here?

1. I first add the user
2. Copy all files recursively for normal files `sudo cp -r
   /home/user1/* /home/user2/ && sudo chown user2:user2 /home/user2`
3. copy all files for hidden files `sudo cp -r /home/user1/.[^.]* /home/user2/ && sudo chown user2:user2 /home/user2`

Transfer rights?

I really have no idea whether this is right

Comment: Have a try using `cp -pPr`. Take a look at the commands manual page for explanations.

Comment: And you want to recursively copy the whole user folder, not the contents. That automatically includes all "hidden" files: `cp -pPr /home/user1 /home/user2`

Comment: but doens't 'p' preserve the rights as they are? Meaning the rights are still with user1. If I have a file 123.txt I want user2 to have the same rights in his folder as user1 has in his folder.

Comment: I want to copy all content AND folders :)

Comment: Sure you want to copy everything inside that folder, I understood. My copy command does that. Did you even bother to try it?

Comment: Certainly you will have to switch ownership after copying, sure. But the `cp -pPr` takes care to recursively copy all files and folders by preserving the exact file permissions which is what you want. As said: read the manual page of the `cp` command...

Comment: wow....this is great. Works perfect. Sorry, I replied before even trying. Do you want to post this as answer so I can accept it as correct?

Comment: Sure, as you like. Have fun!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to recursively copy the whole user folder, not the contents. That automatically includes all "hidden" files. Afterwards you then change the ownership of the new folder:

```
cp -pPr /home/user1 /home/user2
chown -R user2 /home/user2
```

You really want to start reading the manual pages of the tools you use. They contain a wealth of precise information to explore: `man cp`

Comment: I had not previously created the new user (i.e., user2), so I inserted *sudo adduser user2* between the two lines shown in this answer.

Comment: @RayWoodcock You want to use the `-M` flag in that case. Again: read the man pages!